# Button inside ViewCell is not able to navigate to another page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have following ListView in my Page.

```
ListView listof_datewiseRecord = new ListView {                     
    BackgroundColor=ColorResources.PageBackgroundColor,    
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(dataCell)),    
    ItemsSource = listofdate,    
    RowHeight=70,     
};    
public class dataCell:ViewCell
{
   public dataCell ()
   {
    var btnDetails = new Button () {
    FontFamily = "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
    FontSize = 13,
    WidthRequest=60,
    TextColor = ColorResources.TextColor,
    Text="Details",
    BackgroundColor=Color.Blue,
    HeightRequest=35,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
    };

    btnDetails.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>  {
        await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new AdminHome());//I am getting problem here to navigate to other page. 
}
```

I want to navigate to another page onClick event of btnDetails.  But I am not able to find definition for Navigation in Clicked event. Why is it so and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that a `ListView` has it's own click handlers (`ListView.ItemTapped` and `ListView.ItemSelected`) or just use those instead of your `Button` and replace the `Button` with a `Label` or something like that.

If you still want to use a `Button` you need to invalidate the `ListView` handlers in order to get clicking working.

Try adding this:

```
listof_datewiseRecord.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
};
```

Also, according to Xamarin Forms reference on `Button`s inside `ListView`s [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#Enabling_Row_Selection_on_Android) you may need to create a custom renderer on Android.